# Groupby Column and Apply Function to Other Columns Pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by

I want to groupby a specific column and then apply a function to multiple other columns. I want the function to go through each column (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6) individually and (a): drop only the NaN cells in each column, (b) find the total number of 4's in each column and then (c) divide the total number of 4's in each column by the total number of values in the column.

I have tried the following (below), but it doesn't work. For some reason, it doesn't recognize that I am trying to find the number of 4's in each column. I also want to be able to do this for multiple columns, not just one.

```
df.groupby('Team_Name').apply(lambda x: x['Q1'][4]/x['Q1'].sum()).values
print(df)
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add the data sample as text, not as a picture. E.g. try `df.to_dict()` and post in a block between triple backticks (```). Show both input *and* expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare filtered column by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), compare by `4` and get `mean` per groups:

```
print (df)
    Q1  Q2   Q3 Team_Name
0  NaN   4  NaN     team1
1  4.0   8  7.0     team1
2  4.0   4  NaN     team1
3  4.0   0  4.0     team1
4  1.0   2  NaN     team2
5  4.0   4  7.0     team2
6  8.0   4  NaN     team2
7  1.0   4  2.0     team2

out = df.filter(like='Q').eq(4).groupby(df['Team_Name']).mean()
print (out)
             Q1    Q2    Q3
Team_Name                  
team1      0.75  0.50  0.25
team2      0.25  0.75  0.00
```

If need omit `NaN`s if count total number of values in columns count number of `4` by aggregate `sum` and divide by number of values without `NaN`s:

```
df1 = df.filter(like='Q')

out1 = (df1.eq(4).groupby(df['Team_Name']).sum()
                 .div(df1.notna().groupby(df['Team_Name']).sum()))
print (out1)
             Q1    Q2   Q3
Team_Name                 
team1      1.00  0.50  0.5
team2      0.25  0.75  0.0
```

---

Slowier solution with lambda function:

```
out2 = df.filter(like='Q').groupby(df['Team_Name']).agg(lambda x: x.dropna().eq(4).mean())
print (out2)
             Q1    Q2   Q3
Team_Name                 
team1      1.00  0.50  0.5
team2      0.25  0.75  0.0
```

For completness your solution should be changed by lambda functions, but is is slow, so not recommended:

```
out3 = df.filter(like='Q').groupby(df['Team_Name']).agg(lambda x: x.eq(4).sum()/x.size)
print (out3)
             Q1    Q2    Q3
Team_Name                  
team1      0.75  0.50  0.25
team2      0.25  0.75  0.00

out4 = df.filter(like='Q').groupby(df['Team_Name']).agg(lambda x: x.eq(4).sum()/x.count())
print (out4)
             Q1    Q2   Q3
Team_Name                 
team1      1.00  0.50  0.5
team2      0.25  0.75  0.0
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you! Question, what if each of my column headers is different (does not start with Q). How do I adjust for this to ensure that all the columns i want are still being converted to decimal values?

Comment: @obi - Or better `df.select_dtypes(np.number)` for get all numeric columns only

Comment: Great! One more question - is it possible to do all of this, but group by more than just the Team_Name column? I want to group by other columns but can I still apply the lambda function?

Comment: @obi - Then use `.groupby([df['Team_Name'], df['col1'], df['col2']])` instead `.groupby(df['Team_Name'])`

Comment: When I do this, it gives me an error - (unhashable type- 'Series'). Not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: I used the very last solution you provided - the one with lambda.

Comment: @obi - Can you try `df.groupby(['Team_Name','col1','col2']).agg(lambda x: x.eq(4).sum()/x.count())` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not working.

Comment: @obi - Can you more specify `not working` ?

Comment: I get the same error as I described above. I think the dataframe needs to be specified, but can't figure out how to group by other columns.

Comment: @obi - what is `df[['Team_Name', 'col1','col2']].iloc[0].apply(type)` ? Change `col1` and `col2` by column used for `groupby`.